# how many html files for one website?

Tags: html

I'm still a front-end rookie.
And was trying to apply what I've learned on a real website.

So I built one and deployed it.
It includes 4 html files for 4 separate web pages.
And I showed it to my friend.
But he said people usually only has one html file for their websites, and other pages will be using XML in order to reduce the requests to http.

And I checked some websites, and finally find out the difference between their url and mine when directing to pages other than index.

their will be like  **websiteName.com/newPage**
and Mine is **websiteName.com/newPage.html**

So in this case, what kind of document I need to learn?
Pardon me for this silly question.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

> how many html files for one website?

How long is a piece of string?

Seriously. The number of HTML documents you end up with entirely depends on the amount of content you have.

The number of HTML *files* is a bit more variable, but a site with only four pages isn't big enough to worry about dynamically generating content from component parts.

> But he said people usually only has one html file for their websites

This is rubbish.

Some web *applications* will use a single HTML document to host all the JavaScript they need to run. (These are Single Page Applications).

Some websites (even ones which are just informational ones with limited user interaction) will present themselves as an SPA instead of taking a more traditional approach with separate pages. This is a very complicated approach and is rarely worth it.

But *most* sites have lots of different HTML documents. They might generate them from a small collection of template files and a database through.

> other pages will be using XML in order to reduce the requests to http

I have never seen anyone do that.

It is quite common to use the XMLHttpRequest object to load smaller chunks of content over HTTP (usually without going anywhere near XML, which is only in the name because at the time it was designed, XML was sexy so it helped sell it to the developer's managers). Web applications often does this. It doesn't reduce the number of requests though (because HTTP supports caching), just the size of them.

> their will be like websiteName.com/newPage and Mine is websiteName.com/newPage.html

There are lots of different ways you can have URLs without file extensions. The two most common ones are:

- using mod_rewrite (or similar tools) … in which case you could still end up with exactly the same set of static HTML files on your server, just with different URLs
- using server side code (written in whatever programming language you like) with [the front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) (usually in combination with a template language but that could also just load plain HTML documents if you wanted)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a lot of flexibility by using a scripting language like Javascript to access databases and modify your page content on the fly. Javascript can also be used to query your web server without reloading the entire page via AJAX. If you want to learn more about these options read a book like 'Javascript & JQuery The missing manual' by David McFarland. I have a web application that uses 15 pages but it would take hundreds if I was not using Javascript and JQuery.